# LibGDX how do I use one boolean in all class

Tags: class, libgdx, boolean

I have one class that I put the Boolean in but I need to use it
In a different class so can anyone tell me what to do
To get the boolean to work for the other classes to

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8clF1.png image 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxA3N.png

Comment: Give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3445320), we discourage screenshots of code and/or errors so please post code in future instead of screenshot.

---

From screenshot `on` is non-static data member of `playbutton` class. You can't use non-static data member in all class.

You need an object of `playbutton`, if you want to access any non-static data member.

```
playbutton x=new playbutton();
x.on=true;
```

---

I'll recommend you to follow [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in java for better coding experience.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @JosephAustin mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem.